# Lenovo Thinkpad with Windows 11 System Hangs Frequently

Tags: memory, cpu, windows-11, freeze, thinkpad

I am using Lenovo Thinkpad P14s since last 2 years and haven't faced any issues. Suddenly I have noticed that there seems to intermittent noticeable hang while working on light weight applications like "Microsoft Teams" and other applications. CPU / RAM Utilization seems to be very normal. I have also run the detailed system diagnostics for around 7 hours but it has not found any issues with the system hardware.

For example, when I say hang, lets say I am typing some text in a notepad / teams the text won't be visible for few seconds due to this hang and then i need to type again. I am not sure, how this can be explained in other ways. Any suggestions on what might be the triggering point for the intermittent hang?

Other Details:
Installed Ram: 32.0 GB (31.7 GB usable)
OS: Windows 11 Enterprise Version 22H2
Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-10610U CPU @ 1.80GHz

Note: I have already verified that all the system drivers are up-to-date and OS Patches are also up-to-date.

Comment: Try to test Windows integrity by running the commands [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).